# 19.10 - strange wifi issues

Tags: networking, 19.10

When I run from battery, my wifi often switches off, and I cannot enable it again without rebooting. It does not happen when I am on power, only on battery and only since upgrading.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have something like a powertop script or TLP misconfigured?

Comment: Try `iwconfig wlan0 power off`, but change wlan0 to your interface name.

Comment: Look at the logs with `sudo journalctl $(type -p NetworkManager)`

Comment: What does this report? `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I have now set the power off as per heynnema and so far so good.

Comment: cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

Comment: I tried making to change permanent by adding a file to /etc/pm/sleep.d with the command /sbin/iwconfig wlp3s0 power off, but it is still set to on when I do iwconfig after a reboot.

Comment: It happened again, so power management does not solve the issue.  @waltinator - this is the output from the logs:
Dec 15 10:03:47 hein NetworkManager[1320]: <warn>  [1576397027.3036] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): unhandled DHCP event -19
Dec 15 10:03:47 hein NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1576397027.3058] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 88:B1:11:37:41:68
Dec 15 10:03:47 hein NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1576397027.3247] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')

Comment: Don't put logs in unformatted comments - they're unreaable. Rather edt (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1195676/edit ) your question and add the extra info there, properly formatted.